# Forecasting based on few samples

Tags: time-series, bayesian, forecasting, predictive-models

I have to forecast number of enrollments for an international univeristy , challenge is there are only few years of data.So, my data looks somewhat like this:

```
2015 enrolled 70075 
2016 enrolled 73808
2016 enrolled 73808
2017 enrolled 78257
2018 enrolled 83560
2019 enrolled 86753
2020 enrolled 62500 
2021 enrolled 63000
2022 enrolled 78000
```

I have only very limited data and it has up trend, due to covid in 2020 and 2021 the trend has changed. I want to forecast based on these irrgularities which can be any (COVID, economic situation of applicant's country, war situation etc). How can i forecast for the year 2023 based on this few years of historical enrollment data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data can be plotted as follows:[image]

Note: Always plot your data! Especially if you want to forecast.

In covid models, a V-shape recovery has been quite frequent.

The blue line is your data. The red line is a forecast assuming the recent trend (2022) and a slow return (50%?) to pre-covid trend in 2024. The rose line is an "exact" to pre-covid trend in 2024. And the green line is a forecast assuming a pre-covid trend from 2023.

Those trends are really basic, but I wouldn't suggest a bigger statistical or mathematical model because of the lack of a medium run patter.

Comment: thanks for sharing your input, i did plot the data. My question is how can i project data based on less number of sample and scenario as COVID? If you would not suggest statistical or mathematical model then what would you suggest to solve this challenge?

Comment: The suggestion of the answer is to just to calculate the closet growth rate and apply it to the next period, while maintaining the V-shape logic. For example, the red line in 2023 means that: $E_{t+1} = (1+g_t)*E_t$, where $E_t$ is the current enrolled variable, $E_{t+1}$ is the future enrolled number and $g_t$ is the growth rate on period $t$. Therefore, $E_{23} = (1+g_{22})*E_{22} = 78000 * (1 + (78000 /63000 - 1) ) * 63000$                        [P.S. I don't know if this reply goes here or in the answer section]